# How to load the array of sub documents data from mongodb to hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, apache-hive, mongodb-hadoop

We are trying to use the mongodb data in hive, document has array of subdocuments.. How can I load the complex data into hive?

Here is the sample json:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c8cb9913e2f21e062aaa6"),
    "acct" : NumberLong(12345),
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2016-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "averageDailyBal" : "2653.85"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-10-01T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2016-10-31T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "averageDailyBal" : "1840.15"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2016-11-30T17:00:00.000Z"),
            "averageDailyBal" : "2796.14"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As you know The data in MongoDB is stored in JSON format, So you can use any Json serde to parse the data in it.

[Refer this](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)